How to avoid CIImage init from MTLTexture from changing color space?
I have dumped the raw pixel data from my MTLTexture to confirm it is what I expect, but if I create a CIImage from the same texture, the color space changes quite a bit. I can't figure out what CIImage is doing and how to keep it from changing the pixel data in any way.
I've tried the following:
 CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: [CIImageOption.colorSpace: NSNull.self])!
 CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: [CIImageOption.colorSpace: nil])!
 CIImage(mtlTexture: texture, options: [:])

All of these alter the color space in the same way (probably adjusting gamma, it seems).
How can I create a CIImage that just respects the existing RGB data without altering it?

Your method should be correct to remove any color space metadata from the image. However, CI also has a working color space. Depending on what you do with the image, this might cause the gamma adjustment you are seeing. What are you doing with the image? Does the texture actually contain color data?

@FrankRupprecht Hi, thanks for the message. The MTLTexture contains RGBA32 color data. The CIImage is currently used just to create a UIImage for viewing the texture. I have not explicitly set any color spaces anywhere in my code. Perhaps there is a default color space I can't seem to get rid of somehow?

Please try setting the CIContextOption.workingColorSpace when creating your CIContext for rendering to NSNull(). Also, don't use UIImage(ciImage:) and use a CIContext for rendering the image instead.

I just realize you use NSNull.self above. Please try using NSNull() instead.
